# How to solve the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{\log(x)^{c_1}}}{2^{c_2 x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{\log(x)^{c_1}}}{2^{c_2 x}}
$$

I tried to use L'hopital rule by differentiating top and bottom, but it ended up getting more and more complicated. Here, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants.

Comment: Please post your problem as *text,* not as a link to a screenshot. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [Choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) is an important part of [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/42969)

Comment: thank you. I will try to replace the screenshot. I really don't know how to name the title though. Sorry, it is my first time posting a question on SE.

Comment: What are the ranges for c1 and c2? The answer really depends upon the values of the constants.

Comment: By the way, it is not an equation as there is no equals sign. It's an expression (involving a limit) that you are being asked to evaluate.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the title.

Comment: actually, c1 and c2 are supposed to be O(1). Therefore I just said they are constants. If I do not know the range, does it imply that the expression is not solvable?

Comment: Can you find $\lim \ln f(x)$?

Comment: @kiwibird520 What do you mean by c1 and c2 are supposed to be o(1)? Please clarify.

Comment: I have 2 equations initially. equation 1 is e^log(x)^O(1). equation 2 is 2^(O(x)), and O stands for the big O notation. Here, my goal is to investigate if equation 1 is always smaller than equation 2, when x > k, for k a postive constant.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I tried just now. I don't think I can.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a,b>0$
$$\log \left(\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{e^{\log ^a(x)}}{2^{b x}}\right)=\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\log\frac{e^{\log ^a(x)}}{2^{b x}}=\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\log e^{\log ^a(x)}-\log2^{bx}\right)=$$
$$=\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\log^a x-bx \log 2\right)=\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}x\left(\frac{\log^a x}{x}-b\log 2\right)=-\infty$$
As the $\log$ of the limit is $-\infty$ the limit is $0$, provided that $a,b>0$.